# Vim - up-down line movements the cursor changes column position

Tags: vim

While editing a simple text file where every line is nearly to the end of screen, I was expecting vim to retain the column position as I used j and k to move up and down.

Surprisingly, it does not happen. I am using a default install of vim on ubuntu 12.10 and a few plugins (unicycle, speeddating, tex, Align, Alignmaps, genutils, html, foldutil, scratch, surround).

The behaviour I am referring to is: I am in C57-L5. Line 6 is 80 characters long. I hit j, cursor jumps to C1-L6 instead of C57-L6.

What could be wrong? How can I set it right?

Answer (score 1):

open `~/.vimrc` and add these 2 lines

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

close and restart vim.

ps: it will still go to the first column on empty lines, and you might want to set nowrap.